# Unable to get epoch in milliseconds in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have the below airflow code:

```
time_for_run_id = time.time()
run_id=int(time_for_run_id * 1000)

SQL_1 = "INSERT INTO dds_control.dds_control_table (job_run_id,job_start,job_status) VALUES('{}',current_timestamp,'In-progress');".format(run_id)

SQL_2 = "UPDATE dds_control.dds_control_table SET job_end = current_timestamp, job_status = 'Completed' WHERE job_run_id='{}';".format(run_id)

with models.DAG(
    dag_id='DDS_HK_CustAttrRefresh_ID_ibis_bis_acct_mh',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1), 
    catchup=False,
    tags=['ingestion_dag'],
) as dag:
    prev_task = None

    # Insert the start time and config of the job into DDS metadata control table
    job_start_time = CloudSQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=connection_names,
        task_id='insert_dds_ct_start_ts',
        sql=SQL_1,
    )
    
    # Insert the resulting status of the job {success/failed} to DDS metadata control table
    job_end_time = CloudSQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=connection_names,
        task_id='update_dds_ct_end_ts',
        sql=SQL_2,
        trigger_rule='all_done',
    )
 job_start_time >> job_end_time
```

I see that the run_id which is getting passed to the SQL query is different for both the operators. I tried using `{{ execution_date.int_timestamp }}` , but this does not give me the values in milliseconds or nanoseconds. Is there another way for this?

Answer (score 0):

`execution_date` passed in the taskinstance context is a [`pendulum.Datetime` instance](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#formatter).

You can write for your SQL statements:

```py
SQL_1 = """
    INSERT INTO dds_control.dds_control_table (job_run_id, job_start, job_status) 
    VALUES(
        '{{ execution_date.format('x') }}',
        current_timestamp, 
        'In-progress'
    );
"""

SQL_2 = """
    UPDATE dds_control.dds_control_table 
    SET 
        job_end = current_timestamp,
        job_status = 'Completed' 
    WHERE job_run_id='{{ execution_date.format('x') }}';
"""
```